# Nagios Percona Monitoring Plugin

Tags: monitoring, percona, galera

I was reading a blog post on Percona Monitoring Plugins and how you can somehow monitor a Galera cluster using pmp-check-mysql-status plugin. Below is the link to the blog demonstrating that:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/31/percona-xtradb-cluster-galera-with-percona-monitoring-plugins/

The commands in this tutorial are run on the command line. I wish to try these commands in a Nagios .cfg file e.g, monitor.cfg. How do i write the services for the commands used in this tutorial?

This was my attempt and i cannot figure out what the best parameters to use for check_command on the service. I am suspecting that where the problem is.

So inside my /etc/nagios3/conf.d/monitor.cfg file, i have the following:

```
define host{
        use                     generic-host
        host_name               percona-server
        alias                   percona
        address                 127.0.0.1
 }

## Check for a Primary Cluster
define command{
        command_name    check_mysql_status
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-
mysql-status -x wsrep_cluster_status -C == -T str -c non-Primary
}
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        hostgroup_name                  mysql-servers
        service_description             Cluster
        check_command                   pmp-check-mysql-   
status!wsrep_cluster_status!==!str!non-Primary
}
```

When i run the command Nagios and go to monitor it, i get this message in the Nagios dashboard:

```
status: UNKNOWN; /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-status: 31: 
shift: can't shift that many
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You verified that:
`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-status -x wsrep_cluster_status -C == -T str -c non-Primary`
works fine on command line on the target host? I suspect there's a shell escape issue with the ==

Does this work well for you? `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-status -x wsrep_flow_control_paused -w 0.1 -c 0.9`

Comment: The command you provided works in Nagios. So how can i resolve the issue with my command since you mention that is seems there's a shell escape issue with the ==.  How can i rewrite my command : /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-status -x wsrep_cluster_status -C == -T str -c non-Primary to get it to work in Nagios?

Comment: The manual shows you need to quote the == as such:

`pmp-check-mysql-status -x wsrep_cluster_status -C '==' -T str -c non-Primary`

Comment: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-plugins/1.0/nagios/pmp-check-mysql-status.html

Comment: Thanks for the manual and also the help. Will try it out and let you know if i get it working. Thanks @utdrmac.